# Из объекта класса пропадают значения C++

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, деструктор

у меня есть объект, в котором инициализированы 3 динамических массива и 2 переменный типа int.

```
class Graph{
protected:
    int *ValueArr;
    int *IndexArr;
    int *AmountArr;
    int V;
    int D;
public:
```

Есть два конструктора, один по умолчанию:

```
Graph (){
    V = 0;
    D = 0;
    ValueArr = new int[D];
    IndexArr = new int[D];
    AmountArr = new int[V+1];
}
```

А другой принимает значения массивов с клавиатуры:

```
Graph (int mV, int mD){
    V = mV;
    D = mD;
    ValueArr = new int[D];
    IndexArr = new int[D];
    AmountArr = new int[V+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < D; i++)
        cin >> ValueArr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < D; i++)
        cin >> IndexArr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < V + 1; i++)
        cin >> AmountArr[i];
    cout << endl;
}
```

Ещё есть деструктор

```
~Graph(){
        delete[] ValueArr;
        delete[] IndexArr;
        delete[] AmountArr;
    }
```

И есть перегрузка оператора присваивания:

```
Graph operator= (const Graph &B){
    V = B.V;
    D = B.D;

    ValueArr = new int[D];
    IndexArr = new int[D];
    AmountArr = new int[V+1];
    for (int i = 0; i<D; i++){
        ValueArr[i] = B.ValueArr[i];
        IndexArr[i] = B.IndexArr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<V+1; i++)
        AmountArr[i] = B.AmountArr[i];

    return *this;
}
```

И, если создать объект через конструктор по умолчанию (мне это необходимо для создания массива объектов), а потом присвоить ему значения временного объекта, созданного вторым конструктором:

```
Graph A;
A = Graph (5,4);
```

то значения в объекте начнут пропадать, то есть через какое-то случайное количество времени все элементы массивов заменятся на вот такую последовательность "1465662019 1868852841 29559 0 0 0...", что характерно, именно эта последовательность никогда не меняется. Так же, если удалить деструктор из класса, то значения пропадать перестанут.

Comment: У вас нет конструктора копирования, утечка памяти в операторе присваивания.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В твоей перегрузке оператора присваивания есть утечка памяти, сначала очисти память из-под всех динамических массивов, и только потом выделяй новую
И да, конструктор копирования лучше бы написать, он будет примерно такой же, как оператор присваивания. Также возвращать нужно Graph&, а не Graph.
Ещё лучше проверять в таких случаях (когда есть динамически выделяемая память) на самоприсваивание.

Добавь в самом начале в перегрузке оператора присваивания проверка

```
if (this == &B)
    return *this;
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало